# get axios 500 error internal server error

Tags: mongodb

I keep getting this error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/auth/allusersId/648395e2399eaef99a15ef57,648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7,648705e0c0a0395aa659251c 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

when I try to pass to a request an array od id's and to get back an array of emails.

```
useEffect(() => {
    iti.map((dataObj) => {
      return axios
         .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth/allusersId/${[dataObj.usersId]}`),
           .then((res) => {
            setUsersName(res2.data);
           })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
      );
    });
  }, [iti]);
```

```
exports.findUsersById = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
     id: [req.params.id]
    }, 'email', (err, user) => {
      
    if (err,user) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (!user || user.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'User Not found.' });
    }
    const emails = user.map(user =>[ user.email]);
    res.status(200).send(
      emails );
  });
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything works fine. I think the mapping and the whole concept in backend in wrong but I don;t know how to do it else.

Comment: If you mean this line is being invoked: `res.status(500).send({ message: err });` then what is the value of `err`?

Comment: @David ypu mean this? AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …                      sorry but I am new to coding

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this condition?

```
if (err,user) {
```

[The comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) evaluates to the last item in the expression.  So even if there is no `err`, if there *is* a `user` then this condition will be `true`, and the code will respond with an error as designed:

```
res.status(500).send({ message: err });
```

The existence of a `user` doesn't seem like an *error condition*.  I suspect you just meant this:

```
if (err) {
```

Comment: the user thing I got from ChatGPD to be sincere because I didn't kow how to map on those items

Comment: @prettyMaria: Be aware that ChatGPT doesn't know JavaScript.  You may as well ask the Oracle of Delphi or go on a vision quest.  You'd be much better served by tutorials and learning materials, and debugging/testing/validating your code as you write it than by asking an AI bot to just generate a bunch of text that looks reasonably similar to code.

Comment: if I user from if I get this error remove user.map is not a function

Comment: @prettyMaria: If `user.map` is not a function then `user` is not an array.  (At a glance I wouldn't expect it to be, since its name implies singularity and not plurality.)  When you debug, what is it?  Why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: yes, I overlooked a lot of materials but I didn't find an answer and what ChatGPD did was closer to my understanding and to the solution I think. it just makes sense